# How to display icons for Service Locations on Maps?

Tags: navigation, web-app, icons, maps, location

I'm working on displaying icons on maps, there are 3 types of icons:

Pick up point(s): The location that the vehicle should be navigated to

Point of Service: The location that the service will be undertaken

Pointaddress location(s): The location of the addresses

Here is the current solution I'm proposing but not sure if this makes sense and would like some guidance about whether these icons communicate there meaning well?

[image]

Comment: Why do you need point of service? What is it?

Comment: The location that the service will be undertaken once the vehicle has navigated to that pick up point. We need the point of service because it's where the crew need to go after they've been to the pick up point. Sometimes the crew need to walk between the two to undertake the service. See the black dotted line on image above.

Comment: The point of service could for example be the location of a bin store.

Comment: It might be worth considering a two stage process where they navigate to the pickup point location and are then prompted with the more accurate location they need to go to upon arrival.

Comment: This is an overview of the crew and what they are doing so there wouldn't be a prompt.

Comment: Looks like an app we did for Glasgow City Council, do they need to see the address? I making an assumption this is the person who booked the job...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has no right answer. The best way to really know is by doing very good **research** testing maps apps and **prototype** this to test with **real users**. And you can do **monitored and unmonitored tests** to discover the user behaviour and based on their difficulties you can create new prototypes.

But here is my viewpoint:

- The address location looks fine and insignificant for me.
- For the others is quite confusing. Maybe you should try something like in my example.

[image]

It's important to consider:

- What's is the most important information for the user? Give more importance to the icon related to the most important information.
- Which other apps your user uses that have maps? Get as a reference and don't do it so differently.
- The car route is important or just the pickup point?
- Why the point address is so important that is polluting the map?
- Why the user needs the service point? What the user will do there?
- What the step-by-step for the user use your app?
- The user can choose what points he would like to see on the map?

Comment: If you explain a bit more what your app does, maybe we can give some better advice.